# Multiplicative persistence program not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program is supposed to find the multiplicative persistence of an input number but I can't get it to work. It simply closes the window when open it. I can't think of anything that's wrong here.

```
import time
a = int(input("Enter the number"))
s = 1
n = 0
while (a>0):
    while (a>0):
        b = a%10
        s = s*b
        a = a/10
    n = n+1
    a = s
    print(s)
time.sleep(10)
```

```
input = 277777788888899 
expected output = 277777788888899 4996238671872 438939648 4478976 338688 27648 2688 768 336 54 20 0 
current output = 0
```

Comment: Please give an example input, the expected output, and current output

Comment: input = 277777788888899
expected output = 
277777788888899
4996238671872
438939648
4478976
338688
27648
2688
768
336
54
20
0
current output = 0

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I got it working

```
import time

a = 277777788888899
s = 1
n = 0
print(a)
while (a>0):
    while (a>0):
        b = a%10
        s = s*b
        a = a//10
    n = n+1
    a = s
    print(s)
    s = 1 
n = str(n)
print('the multiplicative persistence is '+n)

time.sleep(10)
```

The operator for integer division is apparently // and not /. Welp C++ habits die hard.